# PayPal Donate Button - Integration

Tags: paypal

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

PayPal has a product - the donate button, it has a very nice UI / flow, you click donate and a nice Pop up opens up.

[image: This is screen 1]

[image: This is the Pop Up]

This can be seen at https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/donations and there are limited options for customizing at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/donate_step_1/.

We have a customized app at http://donate.olpejetaconservancy.org/projects/last-male-standing and have integrated PayPal standard via their API. You can try clicking on Donate (it is currently in Sandbox).

Is there any way we can get the same experience, our App and Hosting are not PCI compliant.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You're getting OLD layout due to invalid PayPal variables.

ON0, OS0.

To get new optimized layout, just removed above variables from your donate payment code. It will resolve your issue.

Sample Donate button code: 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&amount=1&business=fundstakpro-fs@vurke.com&charset=UTF-8&first_name=Jhon&last_name=Mac&address1=w&city=wow&country=AU&item_name=Support%20Ol%20Pejeta%20conservancy!%20-%20Ol%20Pejeta&currency_code=USD&custom=87804827-42bc-4eee-b876-c3752b94c74c&notify_url=http://donate.olpejetaconservancy.org/users/ipnPayPal.aspx&return=http://donate.olpejetaconservancy.org/users/TransactionSuccess.aspx&cancel_return=http://donate.olpejetaconservancy.org/